# Jest - replacing mock implementation for named exported function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following code of the NodeJS AWS Lambda function I would like to cover by unit tests with Jest:

**index.js**

```
const { getConfig } = require('./modules/config/configManager');
const BridgeDataProvider = require('./modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
const ClientProcessor = require('./modules/domain/clientProcessor');
const configPromise = getConfig();

exports.handler = async () => {

    const config = await configPromise;
    if (!config.enabled) {
        return;
    }

    const bridgeDataProvider = new BridgeDataProvider(config.bridgeDynamoDbConfig);
    const clientProcessor = new ClientProcessor(config);

    const clients = await bridgeDataProvider.getActiveClients();

    for (const client of clients) {
        await clientProcessor.process(client);
    }
};
```

And I'm trying to mock `getConfig` async function for each test individually, but unfortunately it doesn't work. `await getConfig()` in `index.js` always returns `undefined` Here's the testing code:

**index.test.js**

```
const { getConfig } = require('../modules/config/configManager');
const { handler } = require('../index');
const BridgeDataProvider = require('../modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
const ClientProcessor = require('../modules/domain/clientProcessor');

jest.mock('../modules/config/configManager', () => ({
    getConfig: jest.fn(),
}));
jest.mock('../modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
jest.mock('../modules/domain/clientProcessor');

const defaultMocks = {
    BridgeDataProvider: {
        getActiveClients: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            /** @type {Client[]} */
            const clients = [
                {
                    id: '1234abc',
                    clientcode: 'Amazon',
                },
                {
                    id: '5678def',
                    clientcode: 'Facebook',
                },
            ];

            return Promise.resolve(clients);
        }),
    },
};

/**
 * @typedef {import('../modules/config/config.types').AppConfig} AppConfig
 * @typedef {import('../modules/storage/bridge/models.types').Client} Client
 */

describe('handler', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.resetModules()
            .clearAllMocks();
        
        setupDefaultMocks();
    });

    it('does not handle clients if function is not enabled', async () => {
        getConfig.mockResolvedValue({enabled: false, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: {}}); // this is not working, await getConfig() returns undefined in index.js

        await handler();

        const processMethod = ClientProcessor.mock.instances[0].process;
        expect(processMethod).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
    });
});

function setupDefaultMocks() {
    getConfig.mockResolvedValue({enabled: true, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: {}}); // this is not working, await getConfig() returns undefined in index.js

    BridgeDataProvider.mockImplementation(() => defaultMocks.BridgeDataProvider);
}
```

Test output:

```
 FAIL  test/index.test.js
  ● handler › does not handle clients if function is not enabled

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'enabled')

      10 |
      11 |     const config = await configPromise;
    > 12 |     if (!config.enabled) {
         |                 ^
      13 |         return;
      14 |     }
      15 |

      at enabled (index.js:12:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/index.test.js:48:9)
```

If I put default implementation right inside `jest.mock('../modules/config/configManager', ...)` statement, it will mock resolved value as expected. Why is the mocking in individual test not working and how to make it work?

---

Thanks to [@slideshowp2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6463558/slideshowp2), he pointed me to the fact that `getConfig` is called at the module scope, and I need to require `handler` after doing the mock of `getConfig`. However, if I try to add two tests with differently mocked `getConfig` (`config.enabled = true` and `config.enabled = false`), second test will get the same `enabled = true`. I put the example below based on the [@slideshowp2's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6463558/slideshowp2) answer. I belive I need to remove the `index.js` module cache after each test. I would be grateful if someone would show how to do it.

**index.test.js**

```
const { getConfig } = require('../modules/config/configManager');
const BridgeDataProvider = require('../modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
const ClientProcessor = require('../modules/domain/clientProcessor');

jest.mock('../modules/config/configManager');
jest.mock('../modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
jest.mock('../modules/domain/clientProcessor');

describe('index', () => {

    test('should pass (enabled=true)', async () => {
        getConfig.mockResolvedValueOnce({ enabled: true, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: 'fake bridge dynamoDB config' });
        const bridgeDataProviderInstance = {
            getActiveClients: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([1, 2])
        };
        BridgeDataProvider.mockImplementation(() => bridgeDataProviderInstance);

        const clientProcessorInstance = {
            process: jest.fn()
        };
        ClientProcessor.mockImplementation(() => clientProcessorInstance);

        const {handler} = require('../index');
        await handler();
        expect(getConfig).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(BridgeDataProvider).toBeCalledWith('fake bridge dynamoDB config');
        expect(bridgeDataProviderInstance.getActiveClients).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(clientProcessorInstance.process.mock.calls).toEqual([[1], [2]]);
    });

    test('should pass (enabled=false)', async () => {
        getConfig.mockResolvedValueOnce({ enabled: false, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: 'fake bridge dynamoDB config' });
        const bridgeDataProviderInstance = {
            getActiveClients: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([1, 2])
        };
        BridgeDataProvider.mockImplementation(() => bridgeDataProviderInstance);

        const clientProcessorInstance = {
            process: jest.fn()
        };
        ClientProcessor.mockImplementation(() => clientProcessorInstance);

        const {handler} = require('../index');
        await handler();
        expect(clientProcessorInstance.process).toBeCalledTimes(0);
    });
});
```

Test output

```
FAIL  test/index2.test.js
  index
    √ should pass (enabled=true) (234 ms)
    × should pass (enabled=false) (3 ms)

  ● index › should pass (enabled=false)

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 0
    Received number of calls: 2

      43 |         const {handler} = require('../index');
      44 |         await handler();
    > 45 |         expect(clientProcessorInstance.process).toBeCalledTimes(0);
         |                                                 ^
      46 |     });
      47 | });

      at Object.toBeCalledTimes (test/index2.test.js:45:49)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.95 s, estimated 4 s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@slideshowp2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6463558/slideshowp2), he pointed me to the fact that `getConfig` is called at the module scope of `index.js`, and I need to require handler after mocking implementation of `getConfig`. However, I got the issue of caching the results of `getConfig` because `getConfig` is called at the top-level of the module. That makes multiple tests dependent to each other.

Finally I found a way how to do `require('../index')` in test ignoring the cached state of the module with a help of [`jest.isolateModules(fn)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn). I added `getIsolatedHandler()` which returns isolated `handler` function without any caching state. Here's the final solution:

**index.test.js**

```
const { getConfig } = require('../modules/config/configManager');
const BridgeDataProvider = require('../modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
const ClientProcessor = require('../modules/domain/clientProcessor');

jest.mock('../modules/config/configManager');
jest.mock('../modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
jest.mock('../modules/domain/clientProcessor');

describe('index', () => {
    
    test('should pass (enabled=true)', async () => {
        getConfig.mockResolvedValueOnce({ enabled: true, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: 'fake bridge dynamoDB config' });
        const bridgeDataProviderInstance = {
            getActiveClients: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([1, 2])
        };
        BridgeDataProvider.mockImplementation(() => bridgeDataProviderInstance);

        const clientProcessorInstance = {
            process: jest.fn()
        };
        ClientProcessor.mockImplementation(() => clientProcessorInstance);

        const handler = getIsolatedHandler();
        await handler();
        expect(getConfig).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(BridgeDataProvider).toBeCalledWith('fake bridge dynamoDB config');
        expect(bridgeDataProviderInstance.getActiveClients).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        expect(clientProcessorInstance.process.mock.calls).toEqual([[1], [2]]);
    });

    test('should pass (enabled=false)', async () => {
        getConfig.mockResolvedValueOnce({ enabled: false, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: 'fake bridge dynamoDB config' });
        const bridgeDataProviderInstance = {
            getActiveClients: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([1, 2])
        };
        BridgeDataProvider.mockImplementation(() => bridgeDataProviderInstance);

        const clientProcessorInstance = {
            process: jest.fn()
        };
        ClientProcessor.mockImplementation(() => clientProcessorInstance);

        const handler = getIsolatedHandler();
        await handler();
        expect(clientProcessorInstance.process).toBeCalledTimes(0);
    });
});

function getIsolatedHandler() {
    let handler;
    jest.isolateModules(() => {
        const index = require('../index');
        handler = index.handler;
    });

    return handler;
}
```

Test output:

```
PASS  test/index.test.js
  index
    √ should pass (enabled=true) (263 ms)
    √ should pass (enabled=false) (254 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.289 s
```

Answer (score 1):

See [es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-or-mockimplementationonce](https://jestjs.io/docs/26.x/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-or-mockimplementationonce):

Note: you call `getConfig` in the module scope, so make sure you mock its resolved value before the `require('./')` statement.

Solution:

`index.js`:

```js
const { getConfig } = require('./modules/config/configManager');
const BridgeDataProvider = require('./modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
const ClientProcessor = require('./modules/domain/clientProcessor');
const configPromise = getConfig();

exports.handler = async () => {

  const config = await configPromise;
  if (!config.enabled) {
    return;
  }

  const bridgeDataProvider = new BridgeDataProvider(config.bridgeDynamoDbConfig);
  const clientProcessor = new ClientProcessor(config);

  const clients = await bridgeDataProvider.getActiveClients();

  for (const client of clients) {
    await clientProcessor.process(client);
  }
};
```

`modules/config/configManager.js`:

```js
exports.getConfig = async () => {
  return { enabled: false }
}
```

`modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider.js`:

```js
class BridgeDataProvider {
  async getActiveClients() {
    return []
  }
}
module.exports = BridgeDataProvider;
```

`modules/domain/clientProcessor.js`:

```js
class ClientProcessor {
  async process(client) { }
}

module.exports = ClientProcessor;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { getConfig } = require('./modules/config/configManager');
const BridgeDataProvider = require('./modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
const ClientProcessor = require('./modules/domain/clientProcessor');

jest.mock('./modules/config/configManager');
jest.mock('./modules/storage/bridge/bridgeDataProvider');
jest.mock('./modules/domain/clientProcessor');

describe('index', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    getConfig.mockResolvedValueOnce({ enabled: true, bridgeDynamoDbConfig: 'fake bridge dynamoDB config' })
    const bridgeDataProviderInstance = {
      getActiveClients: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([1, 2])
    }
    BridgeDataProvider.mockImplementation(() => bridgeDataProviderInstance);

    const clientProcessorInstance = {
      process: jest.fn()
    }
    ClientProcessor.mockImplementation(() => clientProcessorInstance)

    const { handler } = require('./');
    await handler();
    expect(getConfig).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(BridgeDataProvider).toBeCalledWith('fake bridge dynamoDB config');
    expect(bridgeDataProviderInstance.getActiveClients).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(clientProcessorInstance.process.mock.calls).toEqual([[1], [2]])
  })
})
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/74137912/index.test.js (10.599 s)
  index
    ✓ should pass (87 ms)

---------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files                        |   76.19 |       50 |   28.57 |   78.95 |                   
 74137912                        |   92.86 |       50 |     100 |   92.31 |                   
  index.js                       |   92.86 |       50 |     100 |   92.31 | 10                
 74137912/modules/config         |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |      50 |                   
  configManager.js               |   33.33 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2                 
 74137912/modules/domain         |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 |                   
  clientProcessor.js             |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 2                 
 74137912/modules/storage/bridge |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 |                   
  bridgeDataProvider.js          |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3                 
---------------------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.271 s
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That's a good catch that `getConfig` is called at the module scope. However, when I try to create another test with mocking `enabled: false`, the value returned by `await configPromise` is still `true`. I believe, the reason is that node module caches the `configPromise`. Could you please tell how should I correctly remove the cache of the module for each new test to make them independent?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Clear the module cache using https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestresetmodules

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use it, however it resets ALL modules, which is not good because I need to reimport all modules. I've used another jest function: [`jest.isolateModules(fn)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn).

Comment: @AndreiKhotko This way is fine as well, nice!